# How can I compile Apache with an old vulnerabe version of OpenSSL for testing?

Tags: https, openssl

I am trying to compile the source of Apache-2.4.27 with custom version of openssl using the option --with-ssl="path to custom openssl directory" during config step itself. I am deliberately using vulnerable version of OPENSSL (v 1.0.1f) so that I can do some kind of testing.But it is always ends up using 1.0.2g as it's OPENSSL version.

How I compile Apache with OPENSSL 1.0.1f?